# Working with Structs within Arrays for new BigQuery Standard SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to find rows with duplicate fields in an array of structs within a Google BigQuery table, using the new Standard SQL. The data in the table (simplified) where each row looks a bit like this:

```
{
  "Session": "abc123",
  "Information" [
    {
      "Identifier": "e8d971a4-ef33-4ea1-8627-f1213e4c67dc"
    },
    {
      "Identifier": "1c62813f-7ec4-4968-b18b-d1eb8f4d9d26"
    },
    {
      "Identifier": "e8d971a4-ef33-4ea1-8627-f1213e4c67dc"
    }
  ]
}
```

My end goal is to display the rows that have `Information` entities with duplicate `Identifier` values present. However, most of the queries I attempt get an error message of the following form:

```
Cannot access field Identifier on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<Identifier STRING>>
```

Is there a way to work with the data inside of a `STRUCT` within an `ARRAY`?

---

Here's my first attempt at a query:

```
SELECT
  Session,
  Information
FROM
  `events.myevents`
WHERE
  COUNT(DISTINCT Information.Identifier) != ARRAY_LENGTH(Information.Identifier)
LIMIT
  1000
```

And another using a subquery:

```
SELECT
  Session,
  Information
FROM (
  SELECT
    Session,
    Information,
    COUNT(DISTINCT Information.Identifier) AS info_count_distinct,
    ARRAY_LENGTH(Information) AS info_count
  FROM
    `events.myevents`
  WHERE
    COUNT(DISTINCT Information.Identifier) != ARRAY_LENGTH(Information.Identifier)
  LIMIT
    1000)
WHERE
  info_count != info_count_distinct
```

Comment: present your query (even if it is erroring) so we can start off of something!

Comment: Sure thing! Edited the question to add two attempts I made.

Comment: did you have chance to check/try my answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try below

```
SELECT Session, Identifier, COUNT(1) AS dups
FROM `events.myevents`, UNNEST(Information)
GROUP BY Session, Identifier
HAVING dups > 1
ORDER BY Session
```

Should give you what you expect plus number of dups.
Like below (example)

```
Session Identifier                              dups     
abc123  e8d971a4-ef33-4ea1-8627-f1213e4c67dc    2    
abc345  1c62813f-7ec4-4968-b18b-d1eb8f4d9d26    3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mikhail, that seems to have worked! Sorry for the delayed response, there was some other noise in our dataset that was confusing me for a while.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! A noobie followup question: does the 

"FROM `events.myevents`, UNNEST(Information)" 

line perform a cross-join of the UNNEST(Information) with events.myevents ON the `Session` key? So UNNEST(Information) essentially made a 2 column table of `session` and `identifier`?

Comment: technically yes, but it is not ON the Session key, rather each row gets CROSSED with entries in Information repeated field. So if particular row has 3 entries in Information - it will produces three rows, and for another row that has for example 5 entries in Information - it will produce 5 rows. If you have more specific questions please post them as a New Question and we will help  you :o)